# Navigation position in middle

Tags: html, css, navigation, padding

I am having some issues getting my navigation to align properly in the middle of its container. I thought having margin-left and margin-right set to auto would help it but on some screens (and browsers it's still not right, apparently too far left.)

Also the 1px border below it looks fine on Chrome but too much padding on Firefox.

Here is the page: http://www.mangdevelopment.co.uk/ghfurnishings/index.html

```
<section id="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  
        <div id="navigation-container">
            <div class="span12">
            <!-- Start Navigation Bar -->
                <nav class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="index.html" class="active">HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">CASE STUDIES</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="profile.html">PROFILE</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="#">NEWS &#38; EVENTS</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="location.html">LOCATION</a></li>
                        <li class="bullet-point"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            <!-- End Navigation Bar --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End of row containing navigation -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation-container {
border-top: 1px solid #9d9f96;
border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9f96;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.nav {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.nav a {
color: #9d9f96;
}

.nav a.active {
color: #636763;
}

.nav li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 15px;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-family: "Copperplate Gothic Light";
}

.nav ul {
width: 900px;
}

.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus {
    color: #636763;
}

.bullet-point {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
.bullet-point:after {
    content:" • ";
    margin-left: 7px;
}
.bullet-point:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your navigation is in the middle, just don't forget that the browser scroll bar has its own width too. Firefox renders fine with me. It exactly the same as in Chrome.

Comment: Your navigations is already in middle

Comment: Mate, please don't delete the contents of a question even if the issue is resolved. It looks very odd. I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css. this will work fine

```
.nav ul {
     width:768px;
     margin:0px auto;
}
```